# php how to use an array to simplify code

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, echo

I have the following piece of php code:

```
<?php 
if(get_theme_mod('typography_setting')=='small') 
{
  echo '12';
} 
else if(get_theme_mod('typography_setting')=='standard') 
{
  echo '13';
} 
else if(get_theme_mod('typography_setting')=='big') 
{
  echo '14';
} 
else if(get_theme_mod('typography_setting')=='huge') 
{
  echo '15';
}
?>
```

Essentially saying, if typography setting is small echo 12, standard - echo 13, big - echo 14, huge - echo 15.

I know this code works fine, but I'm wanting to learn about using arrays and I'm wondering if this code can be simplified by using an array?

Comment: as per your condition it should be switch case

Comment: use in_array() there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not rocket science:

```
$font_sizes = array(
    'small' => 12,
    'standard' => 13,
    ...
);

$size = get_theme_mod('typography_setting');
if( isset($font_sizes[$size]) ){
    echo $font_sizes[$size];
}
```

You can also enhance your code with a more profuse use of the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.